# how to define multiple URLs for the background image of `<body>` so that if one of them was broken, the other one works?

Tags: html, css, background

I used this code for background image of `<body>` :

```
 background: url("http://www.uplooder.net/img/image/39/45732833fc8fdcfd8277ca248d5b608f/QHD.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
```

This image acts really important for my website that if it misses, the whole site will be ugly.

How can I define another additional link so that if the server in which the image is uploaded stops working, the the image gets fetched from the other link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With **CSS 3** you can set [`multiple backgrounds`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)  so if one fails to load you got other one as backup

```css
body {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/1920x860/ffffff/000000'), url('http://placehold.it/1920x860');
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

First background image fails to load here so the other one shows

```css
body {
  background: url('http://placeholdasdf.it/1920x860/ffffff/000000'), url('http://placehold.it/1920x860');
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: That is the cleanest and the easiest way, but then again, not the most optimized one. With this solution, the page will load both images (see this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fwoktdo4/ ), and in the case of the OP, the images are 1.5MB, so that's really not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using JavaScript.

Leave one image as default in the css like you have it.  Then, once the page is loaded, make a GET request using jQuery to that image.  If it returns a 404 error, then repeat for the next image.  When it finally finds an image that doesn't give a 404, you can again use jQuery to set that as the background image.

Answer (score 0):

Download the image and put it in your server.

If you don't have the rights, you shouldn't use it either way.

Comment: The server speed is really low for a 1.5MB picture. I need to use other servers for pictures and other large files.

Comment: Fair enough ! Then the JS solution would be the best in my opinion.